# For what $n$ and $m$ is this number a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Find all positive integers $n$ and $m$ such that $$(2mn+1)^2-4mn(m+n)+n^2+m^2+(n-1)^2+(m-1)^2-3$$ is a perfect square.

Of course $n=m=1$ is a trivial solution and if you put $n=m+1$ (assume WLOG that $n \geq m$), the above expression is equal to $4n^4$ which is a perfect square - But I don't know if this is the only solution. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The polynomial can be expressed as $\frac{1}{4}\left((2m-1)^2+1\right)\left((2n-1)^2+1\right)-1$

Comment: To make this a square using positive integers $m,n$, one can employ a _Pell equation_. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the OP's form,

$$(2mn+1)^2-4mn(m+n)+n^2+m^2+(n-1)^2+(m-1)^2-3 = w^2\tag{1}$$

ccorn and Alyosha showed it is equivalent to the more aesthetic forms,

$$\tfrac{1}{4}\big((2m-1)^2+1\big)\big((2n-1)^2+1\big)-1 =w^2$$

$$(m+n-2mn-1)^2+(n-m)^2-1 =w^2$$

respectively. There are *infinitely* many positive integer solutions to (1) other than $n=m+1$ as we can use a *Pell equation* $x^2-dy^2=1$ to solve it. In fact, we can use infinitely many $d$. For *any* positive integer $m>1$, the solution is then,

$$\begin{aligned}
&n =(2m-3)x^2+4(m-1)^2xy-(m-2)\\
&w = 4(m-1)^2x^2+(2m-3)\big((2m-1)^2+1\big)xy-2(m-1)^2
\end{aligned}$$

where $x,y$ satisfy the Pell equation,

$$x^2-\big((2m-1)^2+1\big)y^2=1$$

For the simplest case when $m=1$, we have the alternative and simpler form,

$n = (x+1)/2,\;\; w=y,\;\; \text{where}\;\;x^2-2y^2=1.\tag{2}$

(Note: Since the $x$ of (2) is odd, then $n$ is an integer.)

Comment: Thank you. I was hiding under my only-a-comment, but really I had no idea how to progress.

Comment: Your welcome. Every time I come across a Diophantine equation with deg 2 (and sometimes deg 3 and 4) where one term $x_1 = 1$, I always try if a subset of solutions can be given by a Pell equation. (Doesn't always work, but sometimes it does.)

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for a comment) I think the question can be made clearer with a rearrangement. The $2(2mn)(m+n)$ smells like a quadratic:
$$((m+n)-(2mn+1))^2=(2mn+1)^2-2(2mn+1)(m+n)+m^2+n^2+2mn$$
$$=(2mn+1)^2-4mn(m+n)-2(m+n)+m^2+n^2+2mn$$
Rearranging,
$$=(2mn+1)^2-4mn(m+n)+m^2+n^2+2mn-2(m+n)$$
$$=[(2mn+1)^2-4mn(m+n)+m^2+n^2]+2mn-2(m+n)$$
And substituting,
$$(2mn+1)^2-4mn(m+n)+m^2+n^2+(n-1)^2+(m-1)^2-3$$
$$=((m+n)-(2mn+1))^2-2mn+2(m+n)+(n-1)^2+(m-1)^2-3$$
$$=((m+n)-(2mn+1))^2-2mn+2m+2n+n^2-2n+m^2-2m-1$$
$$=((m+n)-(2mn+1))^2-2mn+n^2+m^2-1$$
$$=(m+n-2mn-1)^2+(n-m)^2-1$$

It's clear now why $n=m+1$ worked. It's equally clear that $m+n-2mn-1=1 \Rightarrow n=\frac{m-2}{2m-1}$ is a solution (although no positive integer solutions exist).